# memory leak Error in c

Tags: c, string, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have this code

```
char* chars = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));
memcpy(chars, "", 0);
char* hey = "hello doit";
chars = (char*) realloc (chars, 10);
memcpy(chars, hey, 10);
printf("string: %s\n", chars);
free(chars);
```

and I'm getting an error in memory

```
Address "xxxxxxx" is 0 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong here, it looks like Valgrind is having a problem.

Comment: Works for me, valgrind-3.10.1 says "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible."  If you shared the complete program maybe the result is different?

Comment: I don't have leaks, but i do get this error.. in the middle of the valgrind running.

Comment: Also works on the dev-branch, 3.11. [see results here](http://pastebin.com/BBvDi9G4). no leaks detected.

Comment: Ok I isolated the problem. When I print the string, it gives me this error.

Comment: Note that the first `memcpy()` does nothing; copying zero characters into the memory means the memory is untouched.  It doesn't matter because the rest of the code doesn't use the result.  You could use `printf("string: %.10s\n", chars);` to avoid the memory error, but it is better to allocate enough space for the null pointer and to copy the null pointer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 bytes is not enough to contain `"hello doit"` including a string terminator. You don't use any string function here, but perhaps there is other code that does. Please show the complete verifiable example.

You didn't post the whole code, but have now commented *"When I print the string..."* (and edited the question as I typed this).

The sizes need to be 11. You need to copy the terminator too.

```
chars = realloc (chars, 11);
memcpy(chars, hey, 11);
```

Comment: so printf uses the complete string?

Comment: It stops outputting when it reached the string terminator `\0`, which you didn't allow room for, or copy. Hence it ran past the end of the string and gave you strange result.